# How to host Azure Python API via Azure Data Storage

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have python scripts that I want to host as a web app in azure.

- I want to keep the function scripts in azure data storage and host them as a python API in azure.
- I want some devs to be able to change the scripts in the azure data storage and reflect the changes live without having to deploy.

How can I got about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Function App of Runtime Stack Python supported only in Linux Version in any Hosting Plan through Azure Portal.
2. Make the Continuous Deployment setting to GitHub under Deployment Center of the function app in the portal like below:

[image]
After authorizing, provide your GitHub Repository details in the same section.

3. Create the Azure Python Functions from VS Code and deploy to the GitHub Repository using Git Clone through Command Palette.

[image]

4. After that, you can deploy the functions to azure function app.
   [image]

Here after publishing to azure, you'll get the Azure Functions Python Rest API.

> - I want some devs to be able to change the scripts in the azure data storage and reflect the changes live without having to deploy.

Whenever you or dev's make changes the changes in code through GitHub and commit the changes, then it automatically reflects in the Azure Portal Function App.

For more information, please refer this [article](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip251.html) and [GitHub actions of editing the code/script files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=python).